# How to draw the cdf of an exponential random variable in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

So the task is to create a `TikZ` figure of the CDF of an exponential random variable for three different choices of the rate parameter `λ` and for `x` between 0 and 5 (using `λ = 0.5`, `λ = 1` and `λ = 1.5`). The three different CDF’s should be on the same graph and distinguished by colour. The axes should be labelled.

so far I have:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture} [xscale = 1, yscale=1, domain=0:2]

\draw[<->](0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{$x$};

\draw[<->](0,0)--(0,1) node[right]{$y$};

\draw[color=green, thick] plot(\x,{1-\exp(-\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Caption}

\label{fig:my_label}

\end{figure}
```

This is returning error messages saying there are too many closing brackets and I am unsure of where to go from here, as I have tried several different changes and none of them have worked.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

AndréC already told you what's causing the error. But from your title I am wondering if you are looking for something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture} [xscale = 1, yscale=1, domain=0:6]
\draw[latex-latex](0,2.2) node[left]{$y$}  |- (6.2,0) node[below]{$x$};
\foreach \X/\Col in {0.5/green!60!black,1/blue,2/red}
\draw[color=\Col, thick] plot[variable=\x,smooth] (\x,{1-tanh(\X*(3-\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because mathematical functions with `tikz` are not written like `LaTeX` macros. They are written without the reverse bar  `\`

All you have to do is write:

```
\draw[color=green, thick] plot(\x,{1-exp(-\x)});
```

[image: graphe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [xscale = 1, yscale=1, domain=0:2]
\draw[<->](0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{$x$};
\draw[<->](0,0)--(0,1) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[color=green, thick] plot(\x,{1-exp(-\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good catch!!!!!